# CompileError in File uploading

Tags: eclipse, parsing, exception, file-upload, file-io

```
List<?> items =upload.parseRequest(request);
```

The method parseRequest(HttpServletRequest, int, long, String) in the type DiskFileUpload is not applicable for the arguments (HttpServletRequest)

---

When i Run as Server...it gives error on console

> May 13, 2012 7:47:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
>   SEVERE: Begin event threw error
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:185)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:84)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:577)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.(Connector.java:69)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1302)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:619)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:185)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:84)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:577)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.(Connector.java:69)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1302)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:619)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)

---

This is my code in this  code 
`List<?> items =upload.parseRequest(request);` Got error as                              The method parseRequest(HttpServletRequest, int, long, String) in the type DiskFileUpload is not applicable for the arguments 
 (HttpServletRequest)

```
package br.com.ecommerce.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.*;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.*;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.*;


import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DiskFileUpload;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUpload;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext;

import br.com.ecommerce.bean.Produtos;
import br.com.ecommerce.controller.ExceptionController;
import br.com.ecommerce.dao.CategoriasDao;
import br.com.ecommerce.dao.ProdutosDao;
 class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UploadServlet() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        Produtos produto = new Produtos();

        String caminhoTemp = new String("C:\\Users\\vaio\\workspace\\ecommerce\\WebContent\\images\\upload");
        String pasta = new String("C:\\Users\\vaio\\workspace\\ecommerce\\WebContent\\images\\upload");
        String caminho = new String("images\\upload\\");

        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent( request)){

            DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload();

            upload.setRepositoryPath(caminhoTemp);

            try{
    List<?> items =upload.parseRequest(request);//In this line i got error..why?..Pls help

                Iterator<?> iter = items.iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()) {

                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                    if(item.isFormField()){  

                        if(item.getFieldName().equals("nome")){  
                            produto.setProdNome(item.getString().toUpperCase());
                        }

                        else if (item.getFieldName().equals("categoria")){
                            produto.setCategorias(new CategoriasDao().findByPK(Integer.valueOf(item.getString())));
                        }

                        else if (item.getFieldName().equals("preco")){
                            produto.setPreco(Double.valueOf(item.getString()));

                            Double preco = 0d;
                            preco = Double.valueOf(item.getString());
                            preco += 10.00;
                            System.out.println(preco);
                        }

                        else if (item.getFieldName().equals("descp")){
                            produto.setDescPeq(item.getString());
                        }

                        else if (item.getFieldName().equals("descg")){
                            produto.setDescGd(item.getString());
                        }

                        else if (item.getFieldName().equals("espec")){
                            produto.setEspecificacoes(item.getString());
                        }

                        else if (item.getFieldName().equals("itens")){
                            produto.setItensInclusos(item.getString());
                        }

                        produto.setPromocao(0);
                        produto.setDestaque(0);
                }   

                if (!item.isFormField()) {

                    String nome = item.getName().toString();
                    String nomeArquivo = nome.substring(nome.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

                    File arquivo = new File(pasta + "\\" + nomeArquivo);

                    produto.setImagem(caminho + nomeArquivo);

                    item.write(arquivo);

                }
            }





            }catch(FileUploadException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

            try {
                new ProdutosDao().insert(produto);

            } catch (ExceptionController e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        response.sendRedirect("/ecommerce/admin/gerenciarProdutos.jsp");

    }

}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the [DiskFileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/DiskFileUpload.html) class from [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)? If so, make sure your class is importing `org.apache.commons.fileupload.DiskFileUpload`, and not some other class called `DiskFileUpload`.

Comment: I am using this `import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DiskFileUpload;
`